# 正規表現でコマンド文のような文字列を解析する

Tags: 正規表現

`hoge /path/to/source /path/to/target`

のコマンド文の様なフォーマットの文字列があったとします。

この文字列を正規表現等で解析し、各セクションを後方参照でそれぞれ取り出したく

```
([a-z]+) ([^ ]+) ([^ ]+)
```

このような感じで規定しておりましたが、
targetに半角スペースを含む場合"path/to/tar get"というように
ダブルクォーテーションを使って半角スペースを許可したく思います。

使用言語はPythonで、reを使用していますが、Perl準拠の正規表現であれば言語は特にこだわりはありません。
プラットフォームはLinuxベースですがこちらも特に指定は有りません。

現状はまずダブルクォーテーションで括られている範囲を探し
ダブルクォーテーションが存在するなら、括られた範囲内の半角スペースを適当なタグに置換の後
半角スペース区切りで各セクションを取り出し
タグを半角スペースに戻す
という手順を踏んでいますが

1回の正規表現でマッチできるような文がありましたらお知恵を拝借頂きたく思います。

Comment: 使用されるプログラミング言語とプラットフォーム（特にWindowsか否か）が大きく影響しますので、そこを開示していただいた方がいいと思います。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。Perl準拠の正規表現であることを追記しました

Comment: `getopt`や`getopts`コマンドに解析を任せる、という方法もあるのでご参考までに。 / Perlなら`Getopt::Long`モジュールなども。 - [bash によるオプション解析 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/b4b4r07/items/dcd6be0bb9c9185475bb)

Comment: 質問文の根本のところを理解できていない気がしてきました。確認ですが「コマンド文」とは何を指しているのでしょうか？ Pythonで実装された`hoge`コマンドが、起動時に受け取った引数を解析することでしょうか？ それとも何か別の意味があるのでしょうか？

Comment: 「コマンド文」自体に意味はないです。「コマンド文のようなフォーマットの文字列」が渡されたときに、半角スペース区切りで第一象限、第二象限・・・を抜き出していたのですが、最後の象限に半角スペースを使いたいという要望が出てきたので質問した次第となります。(現状はプログラムで数ステップを踏んでパースしていますが、正規表現で一発で出来るようなものなのかということで質問していました。)

Comment: 「オプションの数を可変にしたい」時点で単純な(1行の)正規表現では難しい気がします。ループ処理などで一つずつ解析していく必要があるでしょう。

Comment: オプションの件、承知いたしました。質問を「要素に半角スペースを含む場合」のみに絞ることといたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

だいぶ乱暴ですが、空白を許可するのが二つ目の引数だけであれば、例えば以下の様にできそうです。

```py
pattern = '([a-z]+) ([a-z\/]+) \"?([a-z\/ ]+)\"?'
```

Comment: 繰り返し部分がなければ複雑なものではありませんでしたね・・・失礼いたしました